# Synonym request [google-apps-scripting] -> [google-apps-script]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Please make [google-apps-scripting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-scripting) a synonym of [google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)

Comment: it's been used just twice throughout the entire span of the sie.. not too convinced we need a synonym..

Comment: Shall I re-tag the other two? If I do, will they still appear as possile tag suggestions?

Comment: I'd retagged it before posting the comment. It won't come in tag suggestions.  Feel free to bring this up if tag resurfaces

Comment: @Sathya: can you add the completed tag?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, posted an answer & tagged so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, I've retagged existing [google-apps-scripting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-scripting) questions to [google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).